# Restrict varargs parameter to certain disjunct types

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors, typeclass

I'm currently playing with the scala type system trying to write a DSL. What I'd like to have is the following:

```scala
// custom dsl
val out = TagA(
  TagB(),
  TagC(
    TagC()
    TagA()
  ),
)
```

- `TagA` accepts `0..n` `TagB` or `TagC` parameters, but not `TagA`
- `TagB` accepts no parameters
- `TagC` accepts `0..n` `TagC` or `TagA` parameters, but not `TagB`

So basically I'm trying to pass various disjunct types in a varargs parameter. I thought I could restrict the concrete types that each `Tag` is accepting using typeclasses. Therefore I modeled `TagA`, `TagB` and `TagC` as follows:

```scala
case class TagA[A: TagAChildren](children: A*)
case object TagB
case class TagC[A: TagCChildren](children: A*)


sealed trait TagAChild[-T]

object TagAChildren {
  implicit object TagBWitness extends TagAChild[TagB]
  implicit object TagCWitness extends TagAChild[TagC]
}


sealed trait TagCChild[-T]

object TagCChildren {
  implicit object TagCWitness extends TagCChild[TagC]
  implicit object TagAWitness extends TagCChild[TagA]
}
```

Now this works fine if I'm passing a single type. For example:

```scala
TagA()     // compiles

TagA(      // compiles
  TagB(),
  TagB(),
)
```

However compilation fails if I mix for example `TagB` and `TagC`:

```scala
TagA(
  TagB(),
  TagC(),
)

// could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TagAChild[Product with java.io.Serializable]
```

Obviously the compailer fails to find an implicit. I guess I asked a bit too much from the compiler here... Can anyone think of something to make this work? Any hint or alternative approach is very much apprechiated.

Comment: In TagAChildren, use TagAChild as extension of TabBWitness and TagCWitness. Does it help?

Comment: Doh, messed up types writing down the problem. Thanks for pointing out. The problem remains though.

Comment: There are two solutions to this problem. 1) the magnet pattern - 2) Shapeless. I personally would go with the magnet in this case, it is the simplest solution and multiple other libraries use it to solve this very same problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Wasn't aware that magnet pattern is a thing. Will definitely take a look.

Comment: @Luis awesome, turns out the magnet pattern was exactly what I was looking for. If you want to put together a minimal example I'd accept this as answer. Otherwise I'm going to post an answer myself next week for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I came up with:

```scala
case class TagA(children: TagMagnet[TagA]*)
case object TagB
case class TagC(children: TagMagnet[TagC]*)

sealed trait TagMagnet[A] {
  type Result
  def apply(): Result
}

trait TagMagnetBuilder[A] {
  def build[R](value: R): TagMagnet[A] = new TagMagnet[A] {
    override type Result = R
    override def apply(): Result = value
  }
}

object TagAMagnet extends TagMagnetBuilder[TagA] {
  implicit def tagBMagnet(tag: TagB): TagMagnet[TagA] = build(tag)
  implicit def tagCMagnet(tag: TagC): TagMagnet[TagA] = build(tag)
}

object TagCMagnet extends TagMagnetBuilder[TagC] {
  implicit def tagCMagnet(tag: TagC): TagMagnet[TagC] = build(tag)
  implicit def tagAMagnet(tag: TagA): TagMagnet[TagC] = build(tag)
}
```

For any given `Tag` type I can just extend `TagMagnetBuilder` and define what types this tag should accept. With the above definitions in place the following piece compiles without issues:

```scala
val out = TagA(
  TagB(),
  TagC(
    TagC()
    TagA()
  ),
)
```